# Kylin - Query OLAP cube which is on Hbase?

Tags: apache, hbase, olap, mondrian, kylin

I have installed apache kylin on virtual machine and created a cube with sample data. Kylin stores the created cube on Hbase.

Now I want to query the created olap cube(Perform: drill down, roll up, slice and dice) which is present on Hbase. Is there a way to do this without using any BI tool or kylin UI. I need to basically perform OLAP operations using Java or Python or any programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kylin provides JDBC and Rest API. Check out the below documents.

http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/howto/howto_jdbc.html 
http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/howto/howto_use_restapi.html

Comment: Thanks for the info @Li Yang. Have been thru this. To perform OLAP operations, drilldown, slice and dice do we need to write MDX queries or normal SQL would do this? We cannot write MDX using kylin JDBC. So can we perform these operations using SQL?

Comment: MDX and SQL all translates to relational algebra for execution. You should be able to express drilldown, slice and dice in SQL. If you prefer MDX, google "Kylin, Mondrian, Saiku" together.